# How to access package level annotations in package-info.java runtime from a jar?

Tags: java, annotations

How can i access all package-info classes in a jar in my class path ? I want to access the package level annotations used in these classes.

I want to do the following steps:-

1. Find all the package-info.java classes
2. Get their packages
3. Get the annotation @PackageOwner

Comment: The javadoc package might be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

guava 14+ came  to the rescue :)

following code works

```
public class OwnerFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ClassPath classPath = ClassPath.from(OwnerFinder.class.getClassLoader());
            classPath.getTopLevelClassesRecursive("com.somepackage")
                    .stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getSimpleName().equals("package-info"))
                    .map(c -> c.load().getPackage().getAnnotation(PackageOwner.class))
                    .forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.owner()));

        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

application of the annotation is below for the package-info.java

```
@PackageOwner(owner = "shaikhm")
package com.somepackage;
```

Comment: Addendum: your annotation must itself by annotated with @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) for it to be picked up by this mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

There's a more simple solution, not involving an external api.
You can get the Package object from a class located in the package for which you want the annotations.
And then get these annotations by calling the method getAnnotations() on the package :

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

public class PackageAnnotationsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Package myPackage = AClassInMyPackage.class.getPackage();
        Annotation[] myPackageAnnotations = myPackage.getAnnotations();
        System.out.println("Available annotations for package : " + myPackage.getName());
        for(Annotation a : myPackageAnnotations) {
            System.out.println("\t * " + a.annotationType());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to this [link](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/java-et-les-annotations/generalites-34) that helped me on this question.
I had first read this thread and Parikshit's answer but I didn't want to use an external api.

Comment: With me the problem was that there many "package-info" classes withing the base package. Also i couldn't use "package-info.class.getPackage()" because the compiler throws an error.

Comment: I don't really understand. There can only be one package-info.java file by package. And the way to access the annotations located in this file is to invoke getPackage().getAnnotations() on a real class of the package, not the package "class" (that is not a real class by the way) itself.

Comment: Lets say I have package "com.mercedes.car" which i consider as my base package. I can only have one package-info.java for that package. But i can have a separate package in "com.mercedes.car.engine". Also i don't know what classes exist in the package. So there is no question of AClassInMyPackage.class.getPackage();

Comment: I assumed that your problem was on the way to retrieve info from the package-info.class file and not the way to find all your packages and read their associated annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try the **reflections** library.

https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

A typical use of Reflections would be:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project");

Set<Class<? extends SomeType>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(SomeType.class);

Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(SomeAnnotation.class);
```

Comment: I realized that finding package-info classes won't work. I can't use reflections.getSubTypesOf(package-info.class). It gives a compilation error. May be because package-info doesn't has any class structure.  Wish there was an api to access annotated packages. I tried Package.getPackages(), but it returns only the packages of loaded classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to dynamically load a `Package`, and you can't directly reference an existing class to get the `Package`, then you can use the following to load the package-info class and retrieve the annotation:

```
Package pkg = Class.forName(packageName + ".package-info").getPackage();
PackageOwner packageOwner = pkg.getAnnotation(PackageOwner.class);
```

This removes the need to use an external dependency, and you don't have to be aware of any classes in the target package.

Comment: It should be noted that you don't have to use `getPackage`, you can also get the annotations from the `package-info` `Class` object, which is what `Package#getAnnotation` does internally.